# After making changes to Schema, I am getting Exception occurred when persisting state to the database error

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

My BizTalk application is calling some Azure functions and receiving a response, but due to recent changes, those Azure functions are returning responses in the camel case, so I made changes to some schemas where I just changed the casing to camel case for the required nodes. But after this change, two orchestrations are not working and throwing the following error.

> Uncaught exception (see the 'inner exception' below) has suspended an instance of service 'Bupa.GS.BZ.OBP.ProviderReceiver.FileValidationCompleteAndMixedReport(acdce2c2-3370-b103-30e6-a80725e86ce0)'.
> The service instance will remain suspended until administratively resumed or terminated.
> If resumed the instance will continue from its last persisted state and may re-throw the same unexpected exception.
> InstanceId: 1fd57762-c4bd-49a8-bd4f-ebdd57d37b9d
> Shape name: Send
> ShapeId: 43bb00d5-f4d7-4330-83eb-c3c500bf1d7b
> Exception thrown from: segment 1, progress 28
> Inner exception: Exception occurred when persisting state to the database.

> Exception type: PersistenceException
> Source: Microsoft.XLANGs.BizTalk.Engine
> Target Site: Void Commit()
> The following is a stack trace that identifies the location where the exception occured

> at Microsoft.BizTalk.XLANGs.BTXEngine.BTXXlangStore.Commit()
> at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Service.Persist(Boolean dehydrate, Context ctx, Boolean idleRequired, Boolea*

I can see that the response is received and is being mapped to the schema.

[image: Schema]

But it is not moving to the next stage where I am using this same message and mapping it to another schema in orchestration. All I did was change the casing.

Orchestration image where I have highlighted where I am getting the error
[image: Orchestration image where I have highlighted where I am getting the error]

Port Properties
[image: Port Properties]

Checked all the schemas. All schemas are matching with the response I am getting from Azure functions.

Comment: Did you restart the host instances after deploying the change?  And note: It is failing in the Send Shape, not the receive.  A persistence error usually occurs when you are publishing a message that nothing is subscribing to.